# Jest Unit Test with Framework7

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest, html-framework-7

I'm currently trying to write Unit Test for application that uses Framework7. The setup is with React Context and useReducer. The goal is to mock the Context data and test a component that has been updated after Context values being changed. I found a solution for testing Context Provider, but struggling with component itself. It's giving me error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'emit') at Framework7.emit

Here is my jest.config.js:

```js
const esModules = ['framework7', 'framework7-react', 'framework7-icons', 'framework7-react', 'react-dom'].join('|')

module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts|tsx)?$': 'ts-jest',
    "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "babel-jest",
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    "js",
    "json",
    "jsx",
    "ts",
    "tsx",
  ],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: [
    "/node_modules/(?!(framework7))"
  ],
  transformIgnorePatterns: [`<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!(${esModules})/)`],
  "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$':
      '<rootDir>/assetsTransformer.js',
    '\\.(css|less)$': '<rootDir>/assetsTransformer.js',
  },
};
```

Here is my test:

```
import { Framework7Parameters } from "framework7/types";
import routes from "../../routes"
import App from "../../components/App"
import { renderHook, act } from '@testing-library/react-hooks';

const f7params: Framework7Parameters = {
  id: "io.framework7.testapp", // App bundle ID
  name: "Test", // App name
  theme: "auto", // Automatic theme detection
  // App routes
  routes,
};

jest.mock("socket.io-client", () => {
  const emit = jest.fn();
  const on = jest.fn();
  const socket = { emit, on };
  return jest.fn(() => socket);
});

const state: iState = {
   test: "some test",
   user: "testUser"
}
const dispatch = jest.fn();

const wrapper: React.FC = ({ children }) => (
  <StateContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
    <App /> // <- I had to add App, without it the Framework7 App params not working for components
  </StateContext.Provider>
);

const mockUseContext = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({ state, dispatch }));

React.useContext = mockUseContext;
  
describe('Component test', () => {
  
  test('rendering HomePage', () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => HomePage(f7params), { wrapper });

    // act(() => {
    //   result.current.testFunction() // it's not even getting to functions inside of component
    // })

    expect(screen.getByText(/testUser/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```